# Access local template variable using interpolation inside *ngIf, Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Let's say I have this situation;

```
<div *ngFor="item of items; let i = index;">
  <div *ngIf="variable{{i}}">show if variable{{i}} is true</div>
</div>
```

And I have defined variables "variable0", "variable1",...
How do I access variables in such way using interpolation in *ngIf?
I know *ngIf is a separate template, that's why it can't see the "i" variable, but how can I pass it into the *ngIf template and use it?

Comment: Just a guess, `"'variable' + i"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this should work

```
*ngIf="this['variable' + i]"
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YdHQSTvrnwyTbOIMNqqA?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks, I'm closer to the answer now! But what if I had an array of objects. Let's say: objects = {variable1test : "some string", variable2test : "some string", variable3test:"some string"}. I tried to access them using `<div *ngIf="this['objects.'+i+'test'">` and `<div *ngIf="this['objects['+i+'test]">`, but none of them work. Do you have any solution for such problem too? Thanks!

Comment: You can try this `*ngIf="objects['variable' + i + 'test']"` But `string` is always `true`

Comment: Here is plunker for this case https://plnkr.co/edit/T4R8laqpWCTAb7iZStJi?p=preview

Comment: You sir, are a legend! Don't know why I was trying to use interpolation instead of just "i"...Thank you, it works now!